# Open QGIS2Web using Python Console

Tags: qgis, python, qgis2web

I am currently working with QGIS and for my project I need to start QGIS2Web automatically. Is there a way to start this plugin using the Python Console in QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
import qgis.utils
qgis2web = qgis.utils.plugins["qgis2web"] 
qgis2web.run()
```

Comment: That works! But it only opens the QGIS2Web-Window. Is there a way to start and finish it automatically?